# Breadcrumb looking Tabstrip for navigation

Tags: android, view, navigation

I'm trying to find out how to create this:

https://365webresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Creating-A-Flat-Style-Breadcrumb-With-Pure-CSS3.jpg

My Question:
Where do I start with this?

I'm not really sure where to begin as searching Google for 2 hours has gotten me nowhere.

So far I've come across the following:
`FragmentBreadcrumbs`and `ViewPager`but neither seem to have the design like the link above.

Comment: You will have to make some changes in the layouts of your breadcrumbs to achieve the customisation you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice Library that does exactly what you are looking for. 
Here is the link: https://github.com/JakeWharton/HanselAndGretel 
It's **[Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/HanselAndGretel)** page describes all what you need to get started.

I hope this helps.